# Как после авторизации юзер-бота в боте запустить команды юзербота?

Tags: python, aiogram, pyrogram

Всем привет, как можно сделать чтобы после авторизации юзер-бота в обычном боте написанном на библиотеке aiogram выводить команды юзер-бота(на pyrogram) к примеру:

```
@app.on_message(filters.command("help", prefixes="-") & filters.me)
def helpmsg(app, message):
    message.delete()
    app.send_message(message.chat.id, "Test message help")
```

После авторизации юзер-бота сессия коннектится но не хочет выполнять эту или другие команды

Comment: pyrogram пробовали?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Можно поподробнее?

Comment: вы почитайте про эту библиотеку

Comment: @SeniorPomidor так я же написал то что у меня юзер-бот написан на pyrogram